# Changing the output numbering

Tags: java

How can I achieve that the first student number will be 1 instead of 0? I tried to change i to 1.

```
// Get grades
getGrades(scores, grades);

// Display results
for (int i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("Student " + i + " score is " + 
        scores[i] + " and grade is " + grades[i]);
}
```

Here is what the output looks like now:

> Enter the nubmer of students: 3
>
> Enter 3 scores: 23 45 67
>
> Student 0 score is 23 and grade is F
>
> Student 1 score is 45 and grade is C
>
> Student 2 score is 67 and grade is A

Comment: `"Student "+ (i+1) + "` Simply change `i` to `(i+1)`

Comment: That is your solution Stanmoonie^^

Answer (score 2):

Your code is good, just change your print as the following:

```
System.out.println("Student " + (i + 1) + " score is " + scores[i] + " and grade is " + grades[i]);
```

`(i + 1)` will output the offset that you want.

Answer (score 1):

Your code need a small change in for loop.

```
Integer studentNumber = i + 1;
System.out.println("Student " + studentNumber + " score is " + scores[i] + " and grade is " + grades[i]);
```

In arrays first index is 0, so if you want count from 1 you should create property for it.